# 3 party payments where facilitator != payee

Tags: paypal

According to this blog from 2013: http://whyidentity.blogspot.nl/2013/03/under-hood-restful-payments-api.html, the paypal REST API does not support payments where the payee is not the facilitator.

The scenario is required for example when a web application wants to be able to collect payment for several administrators.

Recently support for billing plans has been added and the plan object does have a payee object.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#plan-object

Am I correct to assume:
1. Billing plans do support the scenario where the payee is not the facilitator?
2. The only way to create a payment where the payee is not the facilitator is to create a plan containing 1 payment?

Cheers,

Sam

Comment: I would recommend sticking with the Adaptive Payments API for now (Classic API).  It's much more mature than REST and it's not going anywhere.

Comment: That answers exactly 0 out of 2 questions i posed...

Comment: Which is why I left it as a comment and not an answer.  It would solve your problem, by the way.  But go ahead, be a smart ass and see how much help you get in the future.